# Inserting value from span tag into SQL database

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a form filled with 24 checkboxes that a user fills in, underneath these checkboxes I have 2 span tags. One counts how many are checked, and the other displays what percentage it is. When I submit this form, I get the following error: Undefined index: #countcheckboxes in **D:\inetpub\wwwroot\SMT_24_Point_Check\newAudit.php** on line **33**

These are my span tags at the bottom of the form...

```
 <div class="count-checkboxes-wrapper">
 Total score: <span id="count-checked-checkboxes" 
 name="countcheckboxes">0</span> out of 24 checked
 </div><br>
 <!-- button to show div below -->
 <input type="button" value="Show Audit Score" onclick=showDiv()>
 <!--div showing total audit score as percentage-->
 <div id="percentDiv"; style="display:none;" class="percentage-checkboxes- 
 wrapper">
 Audit Result:<span id="percentage-checked-checkboxes" 
 name="percentagecheckboxes"> 0</span> %
 </div>
```

On the newAudit.php page, this is the post tags I have for those 2 span tags...

```
$totalChecked = $_POST['countcheckboxes'];
$auditScore = $_POST['percentagecheckboxes'];
```

The out put from the checkboxes displays: Total score: 2 out of 24 checked
And after 'show audit score' is clicked, it says 'Audit result: 8%. I need the values of 2 and 8% to be inserted into the database.

Comment: Spans are not form elements, they do not get sent to the server. To POST them, you'd need a form containing `input` elements with those values, or some JS to get the values directly from those elements and either use an AJAX request to POST them, or perhaps populate a hidden form and submit that. Just a couple of examples.

Comment: How do you submit this form? AJAX or POST ?

Comment: @Jonnix - Thank you, I'll look into using a AJAX request.

Comment: @Shudhansh - My form method is POST and I used AJAX to submit it.

Comment: you should catch event submit before send ajax like :
`$('form').submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var that = this;
    $.post('url', function() {
        that.submit();
    });
});`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are lot of options for you to get the values rather that using meaningless `name` attribute over `span`.

1. Use a `data-count` attribute over both divs i.e., `count-checked-checkboxes` and `percentagecheckboxes`. With the same function, that update the counts, do update the data-attributes. At the time of data post, get those values by `let checkCount = $('#count-checked-checkboxes').attr('data-count');` and so on.
2. Use a hidden input box in the place of span, and update the values of those box with the same update function, and get the values by using `let checkCount = $('#count-checked-checkboxes').val()` and so on.
3. ( Not recommended ) use the text value of those span by using `let checkCount = $('#count-checked-checkboxes').text()` and so on.